# Efficient use of 'Directory.GetFiles' with 'StartsWith', 'Contains' and 'EndsWith' to filter file names

Tags: c#, file, filtering, contains, startswith

Is there a more efficient way to filter file names using Directory.GetFiles and 'StartsWith', 'Contains' and 'EndsWith' with rather than the way I am currently doing it?

```
        _files = Directory.GetFiles(_path);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_startsWith))
        {
            _files = _files.Where(x => x.StartsWith(_startsWith)).ToArray();
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_contains))
        {
            _files = _files.Where(x => x.Contains(_contains)).ToArray();
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_endsWith))
        {
            _files = _files.Where(x => x.EndsWith(_endsWith)).ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: The very slowest part will always be `Directory.GetFiles`, which is _almost_ unavoidable. Searching for the strings is comparatively negligible, that's not what you want to improve, is it?

Comment: There is an overload of GetFiles() where you can provide a searchpattern, have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should switch to `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` cause it is lazy and doesn't need to built up the complete list in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think following overloads will help you:

```
Directory.GetFiles(strPath, "*" + strFilter, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly); // to get behaviour of EndsWith

Directory.GetFiles(strPath, "*" + strFilter + "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly); // to get behaviour of Contains

Directory.GetFiles(strPath, strFilter + "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly); // to get behaviour of StartsWith
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to cram everything into a single line of Linq, you can do something like the following:

```
_files = _files.Where(_ => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(_startsWith)).Where(x => x.StartsWith(_startsWith)).ToArray();
```

However, as mentioned above, the Directory.GetFiles will almost certainly be the slowest part of the code here and you are better off sticking with something which is easier to read.